# Return a vector as parameter

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I have these functions:

```
vector<int> foo1() {
    vector<int> v;
    return v;
}

void foo2( vector<int>& parameter ) {
    // Do something
}

void foo3( vector<int> par ) {
    foo2( par );
}
...
foo2(foo1());   // Doesn't work (1)
foo3(foo1());   // Works (2)
```

Is there a way to keep function foo2 as it is, as it is the optimal way to pass vectors as parameters, and maybe overload it to make (1) work? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary. Anyway, what would be the point of modifying the temporary return value of the function call if it just gets destroyed right after?

Comment: @Sval Never pass vector by value. It is hugely unoptimal.

Comment: @satuon, Unless you need to copy it anyway.

Comment: @chris I just need the values it contains ( it is not actually a vector of ints, it's a vector of strings ) to print them, and I didn't want to get verbose. But I wondered for solutions for every kind of vectors, it may be useful to know if it can be done.

Comment: If you don't need to modify the contents of the vector, `foo2` should take it as a `const vector<int>&`. Then there's no problem with passing a temporary.

Comment: "`is the optimal way to pass vectors as parameters`" No, it's certainly not...

Comment: It works, thanks! And if I needed to modify that I would have to copy it to somewhere, right? It can't be done in a single instruction?

Comment: @K-ballo Uhm, I've read that in general you should pass vectors as references instead of copying them, if you know of I better way I would be happy to read about it, I've started using stl stuff only recently..

Comment: @Svalorzen: Check this out http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/ , and that is **C++03** with no _move-semantics_.

Comment: @K-ballo: Abrahams states that passing by value is at least as efficient as explicitly copying within the function and possibly much more efficient. However, this only applies when the function needs its own private copy of the vector to work with. I'm not sure why, but he only offers this qualifier deep down in the comments (“The guideline is: Pass by value any arguments that you would *otherwise* copy explicitly.”). In the above code, if `foo2` doesn't need its own copy of the vector, passing by value would be an egregious waste of CO2 unless you know that you will only ever pass rvalues in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing by reference is typically use for 'out parameters', parameters used to return a value to the caller:

```
void bar(int &i, int &j);

int i, j;
bar(i, j); // sets i and j
// use i and j values here
```

C++ happens to disallow binding temporaries to non-const lvalues. So this does not work:

```
bar(1,2);
```

However, there is a need to allow passing temporaries without copying them, and prior to C++11 this need was filled by allowing temporaries to bind to *const* lvalue references. This is a special rule which still prevents mistakenly using a temporary as an out parameter, but allows copying to be avoided.

Since you're using the vector as an input parameter and not an output parameter, that would be the appropriate way to avoid copying:

```
void foo2(vector<int> const &parameter) {
    // Do something
}
```

If the 'Do something' code does eventually make a copy of the vector then you'd be better off doing this:

```
void foo2(vector<int> parameter) {
    // Do something
}
```

Because this allows the compiler to optimize the copying for you in specific cases of calling `foo2`, perhaps eliminating the copy.

Comment: I already tried to put const after vector<int>, and it didn't work ( I tried again now, and it still doesn't work ). If I put the const before it the program compiles though.

Comment: @Svalorzen `vector<int> const &` and `const vector<int> &` are identical types. I just prefer placing `const` after. If there's another problem it's because you haven't described some aspect of the problem, because this [works fine](http://ideone.com/fglgL0).

Comment: I think I forgot some const here and there, and putting const before it made the compiler ignore them in some way. Now it works both ways, thanks! I'll accept this as soon as I can.